# Is it possible to make this for loop not change the variable and still have it make the same results?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, sqlite

Ok, so I am trying to make a gui for a database that stores names and specific information on a person.  Right now I am at just about the end of this project and I've come across an issue that I believe can be solved.  I have a for loop that changes a variable(Label) and .packs that variable to the GUI, this is all great up until I am required to delete this variable(Label) as it becomes stated as the last one as it is a for loop, any ideas?

```
def read_from_database():
    global label4
    global But2
    global Counter
    global e4
    global Namelist
    if(Counter == 0):
        Counter += 1
        But4.config(relief=SUNKEN)
        But5.config(relief=SUNKEN)
        But6.config(relief=SUNKEN)
        sql = ("SELECT * FROM nameinfo")
        for row in c.execute(sql): # Here is the for loop
            Namelist = Label(root, text=row[0])
            Namelist.pack()
        label4 = Label(root, text="Name:")
        label4.pack(side=LEFT)
        e4 = Entry(root)
        e4.pack(side=LEFT)
        But2.pack()

def submit(): # submit your results
    global Readinfo
    name = (e4.get())

    label4.destroy()
    But2.pack_forget()
    e4.destroy()
    sql = ("SELECT * FROM nameinfo")
    for sql1 in c.execute(sql):
        Namelist.pack_forget()


    sql = "SELECT * FROM nameinfo WHERE name = ?"
    for row in c.execute(sql, (name, )):
        NAME = ('Name: ' + row[0])
        AGE = (', Age: ' + str(row[1]))
        COLOR = (', Favorite color: ' + row[2])
        Readinfo = Label(root, text=NAME + AGE + COLOR, bg='black', 
    fg='white')
        Readinfo.pack()

    Clear.pack(padx=8, pady=5)

def clear(): # How I later clear the results
    global Counter
    Counter += -1
    try:
        Readinfo
    except NameError:
        pass
    else:
        Readinfo.pack_forget()
Clear.pack_forget()
But4.config(relief=RAISED)
But5.config(relief=RAISED)
But6.config(relief=RAISED)

Clear = Button(root, text='Clear', fg='black', bg='green', command=clear)
But2 = Button(root, text='Submit', bg='white', fg='blue', command=submit)
```

Ok, that is all the code that is included in my reading section.  I know it is extremely sloppy and some parts might not be needed or anything.  I will take advice in future programming and probably this one too, I am very new and will take suggestions:).

Comment: You may have more luck with this question if you provide a minimal example of the problem. The sql, other buttons, and etc... are not needed for the problem. Something small we could actually run would be great.

Comment: @tdelaney yea, I'm really sorry about that, I'm kind of new to this site.

Comment: No worries. Something short and runnable ups the odds that someone will fiddle with it and offer suggestions. And its more likely to be useful to others who have similar questions.

Comment: If I understand, maybe I am wrong, it looks you are creating labels in a for loop by rewriting over the same var name, and packing it. Later you need to reference the labels and you can't. Just append the label widgets into a list, instead of rewriting the same name. Later you can refer to the list with the indexes you want (or with another for loop).

Comment: @progmatico surprisingly enough I had the same idea after thinking about it for a while and it worked greatly.  I still heavily appreciate your answer, thank you.